# PL/SQL Procedure X references a view Y

Tags: view, reference, plsql, procedure

What does it means that "reference view"? Is it that there is any statement in the procedure which mention given view. Any command for example "delete from Y where ...." or anything similar, please? Does it mean that reference is any command containing that view Y, please?

It is part of questions and answers I have here and one of answer is that "Y is a direct dependent of X"?
Does it mean that procedure create that view?

Here is whole question and answer.

Consider this scenario: A procedure X references a view Y that is based on a table Z. Which two statements
are true? (Choose two.)

Y is a referenced object.

Y is a direct dependent of X.

Answer (score 2):

If a procedure references a view, that means that the PL/SQL compiler has determined that the procedure uses the view in some way.

For example, the following procedure references the view `v_some_view`, and so has a dependency on it:

```
PROCEDURE example (p_count OUT INTEGER)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO p_count FROM v_some_view;
END;
```

The procedure can't be valid without the view existing.  If we were to drop the view, the procedure would no longer be valid, as it would attempt to select from a view that does not exist.  The PL/SQL compiler cannot compile this procedure without the view existing.

It's not sufficient for the view to exist; it must also be valid.  Errors in the view will cause the procedure to fail to compile.

The only ways a procedure can reference a view is with a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `MERGE` or `DELETE` statement using the view.  It is not possible to `CREATE` a view in PL/SQL without `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, and even if you do this the procedure can't subsequently refer to the newly-created view as the view will not exist at compile-time.

For example, if `my_view` does not exist, the following procedure will not compile:

```
PROCEDURE invalid
IS
  p_count    INTEGER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM DUAL';
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO p_count FROM my_view;
  dbms_output.put_line('Count was ' || p_count);
END;
```

So, one way of thinking about dependencies is 'can object Y be valid only if X exists and is valid?'.  If the answer to this question is yes, then Y has a dependency on X.

If you have access to an Oracle database, take a look at the data dictionary views `USER_DEPENDENCIES` and `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` to see some examples of dependencies between objects.